# Mongoose Validation Race Condition?

Tags: validation, node.js, mongoose, race-condition

I have a model called Application:

```
var ApplicationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name       : {type: String, validate: [uniqueName, 'Unique Name']},
dateCreated: Date,
containers : [ContainerSchema]
});
mongoose.model('Application', ApplicationSchema);
var Application = database.model('Application');
```

It calls a validation function called uniqueName when it saves:

```
function uniqueName(name)
{
console.log('In Unique Name function');
Application.find({}, function(error, documents) {
    for(var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
        if(documents[i].name == name) {
            console.log('About to return false');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
return true;
}
```

Later on in the code I put some data in the model and save it:

```
newApplication.name = request.body.name;
newApplication.save(function(error) {
    console.log('Callback for save');
    if(error) {
        console.log('error if statement');
        response.statusCode = 409;
        response.end();
    }
    console.log('Done with callback');
});
response.statusCode = 201;
response.end();
```

When I test this with a name that is not unique, I get a 201 response and the following output from my terminal:

```
In Unique Name function
Callback for save
Done with callback
About to return false
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this really a race condition in Mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your validator is asynchronous (as it is here) it needs to accept a second parameter which is a callback that you must call with true or false, depending on whether that validation passed.  So:

```
function uniqueName(name, callback)
{
    Application.find({}, function(error, documents) {
        for(var i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
            if(documents[i].name == name) {
                return callback(false);
            }
        }
        return callback(true);
    }
}
```

However, this is not very efficient; you should either:

Filter your `find` instead of getting all docs and manually searching them.  e.g.

```
Application.find({name: name} ...
```

OR even better:

Create a unique index on `name` and let mongo ensure uniqueness for you. e.g.

```
var ApplicationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type: String, unique: true}, 
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you! You're right, I didn't realize there was a unique index.

Comment: You should emphasize how the unique index is really the only way to solve this problem. Doing a lookup in a validator like this results in a race condition. After your lookup in the validator returns to you, another document could be inserted into the collection with the same value for `name`. Your document would still pass validation and continue to write, resulting in two documents with the same value for `name`.  MongoDB’s unique index guarantees that this won’t happen (as long as you don’t disable index checking when saving).